# Raylib: audio popping and cracking

Tags: audio, go, raylib

I'm trying to play a "simple" generated looped sinusoidal wave with raylib and Go but, although it plays I also get audible cracks.

Checking some online examples (like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1VQuMziTek), I see that a common problem might be that the generated wave does not stitch perfectly on the extremes and can cause those glitches, but applying the same fix as in the video (tracking the phase) seems to not work for me.

Could it be the buffer gets empty for too long before I'm able to fill it again? How can I debug this?

Here is an isolated reproducible example:

```
package main

import (
    rl "github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib"
    "math"
)

const sampleRate = 44100
const streamBufferSize = 1024

type Oscillator struct {
    phase       float64
    phaseStride float64
}

func (o *Oscillator) advance() {
    o.phase += o.phaseStride
    if o.phase >= 1 {
        o.phase -= 1
    }
}

func NewOscillator(frequency float32, sampleDuration float32) *Oscillator {
    return &Oscillator{
        phase:       0,
        phaseStride: float64(frequency * sampleDuration),
    }
}

func main() {
    rl.InitAudioDevice()

    stream := rl.LoadAudioStream(
        uint32(sampleRate),
        32,
        1,
    )
    defer rl.UnloadAudioStream(stream)
    defer rl.CloseAudioDevice()

    rl.SetAudioStreamVolume(stream, 0.10)
    rl.SetAudioStreamBufferSizeDefault(streamBufferSize)
    rl.PlayAudioStream(stream)

    samples := make([]float32, streamBufferSize)
    sampleDuration := float32(1) / sampleRate
    oscillator := NewOscillator(440, sampleDuration)

    for {
        if rl.IsAudioStreamProcessed(stream) {
            updateSamples(samples, oscillator)
            rl.UpdateAudioStream(
                stream,
                samples,
                streamBufferSize,
            )
        }
    }
}

func updateSamples(samples []float32, oscillator *Oscillator) {
    for t := 0; t < streamBufferSize; t++ {
        oscillator.advance()
        x := 2 * math.Pi * oscillator.phase
        samples[t] = float32(math.Sin(float64(x)))
    }
}
```